# Rails - query treats negative decimal value as positive

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Transaction model which contains amongst others: start_balance and end_balance, both of which are decimal fields.  Transactions where the start balance is greater than the end balance are the result of a charge and payments are the opposite.

I have this query looking only for transactions who's end_balance is greater than the start_balance(payments)

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.payments
    where(:end_balance > :start_balance)
  end

end
```

Both fields often contain negative values.  This seems simple enough but interestingly, when I run this query it treats all records as though they are positive.  For example, the following code:

```
Transaction.payments.first(10).each do |t|
  puts t.start_balance.to_s + " start"
  puts t.end_balance.to_s + " end" 
end
```

produces:

```
0.0 start
-6212.0 end
-6212.0 start
0.0 end
0.0 start
-6212.0 end
-6212.0 start
0.0 end
0.0 start
-6212.0 end
-6212.0 start
0.0 end
0.0 start
-6212.0 end
-6212.0 start
0.0 end
0.0 start
-6212.0 end
-6212.0 start
0.0 end
```

Looking at this, it would seem that its treating all numbers as though they were positive.  Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot do:

```
where(:end_balance > :start_balance)
```

Instead you must do something like:

```
where("end_balance > start_balance")
```

Ruby evaluates the first immediately:

```
2.1.2 :001 > :end_balance > :start_balance
=> false
```

Whereas the second gets passed as a condition to your db.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, your explanation makes perfect sense, and after altering my queries, the problem is gone.  But perhaps more importantly your answer helped to reinstate my sanity.  Seriously, I was checking -5.0 > 5 just to make sure I hadn't lost my mind